# Making AUC the metric to optimize training

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret, training-data

I have 2 levels factor outcome variable in my dataset

```
str(as.factor(train2$outcome))
 Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 ...
```

When i use a train function with default metric to optimise evrt seems OK.

```
cvCtrl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=3, repeats=5,classProb = TRUE)
modelFit <- train(as.factor(outcome) ~., data=train2, method="rf", trControl =cvCtrl)
```

But i want to optimise AUC. So i use this code

```
cvCtrl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=3, repeats=5, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,classProb = TRUE)
modelFit <- train(as.factor(outcome) ~., data=train2, method="rf", trControl =cvCtrl, metric="ROC")
```

And i get an error:

```
Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : 
  final tuning parameters could not be determined
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Did you see the warning that

> `At least one of the class levels are not valid R variables names; This may cause errors if class probabilities are generated because the variables names will be converted to ...`

Using `0` and `1` as factor levels is a bad idea and the source of the error.

Max

Comment: still looking for an answer to this. does `train(metric = 'ROC', trControl = trainControl(summaryFunction = 'ROC'), ...)` do the trick?